# Check if a specific class and value exist in HTML using beautifulsoup Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm writing a script for **scrape** the website "yelp.fr" but to scrap the number of stars the class is generating automaticly:
class="i-stars i-stars--regular-4 rating-large" ==> 4 starts
class="i-stars i-stars--regular-3-half rating-large" ==> 3.5

My question how i can do this? and how can i etst if class exist or not on the html page

```
CITIES = "la rochelle(17000)"
places = "Bars"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.yelp.fr/search?find_desc="+places+"&find_loc="+CITIES+"")
page = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"lxml")
etoiles=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix"})
                    
etoiles.get_attribute("title")
if etoiles:
    print "ok"
else:
    print "not "
```

some times class biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix  not exist as bellow
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `title` of that `DIV` contains the number of stars/rating. You can get it like

```
ratings = soup.select(".i-stars")
for rating in ratings:
    print rating.attrs['title']
```

Comment: i tested you proposition but the field doesn't have stars like "le Set bar" affect a default value 5.0 stars

Answer (score 0):

I solve the probleme using this:

```
yelp_url  = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=%s&find_loc=%s&start=%s"%(place,city,str(id))

        headers1 = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
        response1 = requests.get(yelp_url).text
        parser = html.fromstring(response1)
        print "Parsing the page"
        listing1 = parser.xpath("//li[@class='regular-search-result']")
for results in listing1:
if raw_ratings:
                        ratings = re.findall("\d+[.,]?\d+",cleaned_ratings)[0]
                    else:
                        ratings = 0
                    price_range = len(''.join(raw_price_range)) if raw_price_range else 0
                    address  = ' '.join(' '.join(raw_address).split())
                    address=unidecode(address)
                    reservation_available = True if is_reservation_available else False
                    accept_pickup = True if is_accept_pickup else False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_review_count = results.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'review-count')]//text()")
                    raw_price_range = results.xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'price-range')]//text()")
if raw_ratings:
                        ratings = re.findall("\d+[.,]?\d+",cleaned_ratings)[0]
                    else:
                        ratings = 0
                    price_range = len(''.join(raw_price_range)) if raw_price_range else 0
```